# PaginationSizeSelector - All option in dropdown to display all rows of table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, tabulator

I am using Tabulator for table component. Is there any way that we can have all option in pagination so that all rows of table can be displayed if the user selects all option?

Also, How do we pass pagination element if we want pagination to be displayed at the top of the table?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no option for displaying all rows, though you could just set the page size to the current number of rows which would have the same effect.

If you want the pagination controls to appear inside the tabulator then the only option is inside the footer. If you want them to be added to an existing element outside the table then you can pass the element to the ***paginationElement*** setup option and Tabulator will insert the elements into this instead of the footer:

```
var paginationElement = document.getElementByID("#pagination-controlls"); //find existing pagination element

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    pagination:"local",
    paginationElement:paginationElement, //build pagination controls in this element
});
```